# pandas: subtracting two columns and saving result as an absolute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the code where I have a csv file opened in pandas and a new one I'm creating. There's a row I need to create "two last lines commented out" of an absolute value of subtracting two rows. I've tried a number of ideas in my head all bring an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(filename_read)
ids = df['id']

oosDF = pd.DataFrame()
oosDF['id'] = ids
oosDF['pred'] = pred
oosDF['y'] = df['target']
#oosDF['diff'] = oosdF['pred'] - oosDF['y']
#oosDF['diff'] = oosDF.abs()
```

Comment: What kind of error? Maybe need `oosDF['diff'] = (oosdF['pred'] - oosDF['y']).abs()`

Comment: I think you just need to change oosdF to oosDF for it to work in the second last line

Comment: thanks, let me fix it

Answer (score 13):

I think you need for new `DataFrame` by subset (columns names in double `[]`) and then get [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) value of difference of columns:

```
oosDF = df[['id','pred', 'target']].replace(columns={'target':'y'})
oosDF['diff'] = (oosDF['pred'] - oosDF['y']).abs()
```

Comment: `pred` is made from an ML prediction so is not previously in `df` but I might go with adding it to `df` first. The error i get is `NameError: name 'oosdF' is not defined`

Comment: oosDF['diff'] = (oosdF['pred'] - oosDF['y']).abs()

Comment: It is really weird, if change `oosDF` to `df1` it should working.

Comment: looks like i have a typo let me try that first

Answer (score 1):

In your first commented line, you have `oosdF` instead of `oosDF`.

In your second commented line, you're setting the column to be `abs()` applied to the whole dataframe. That should be `oosDF['diff'].abs()`

Hope this helps!